# mex in matlab r2011 - out of memory error

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to use MEX. I use MATLAB R2011a and my compiler is

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0

I use this simple file:
http://www.shawnlankton.com/2008/03/getting-started-with-mex-a-short-tutorial/

and `helloworld.cpp` works, but `demo.cpp` does not. I either get a "out of memory" error, or MATLAB just crashes...

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I just have an ubuntu with gcc4.7.2-2, but for me everything works fine. How do you invoke "demo"? Have you tried to add some outputs to the demo.cpp, to get to the point where it crashs? Have you tried to debug the code using http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-c-c-language-mex-files.html

Comment: Check if you have written the code exactly the way it is.
Also run clear helloworld once and recompile.
As said by @Tik0 check adding outputs or debugging.